# f# canopy testing framework assert ==

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

While this command is successful

```
".navbar-brand" == "AUP"
```

Can anyone tell me why this line:

```
(element ".navbar-brand") == "AUP"
```

results in this error?

> *Error: Can't check equality on OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement because it is not a string or
>   alert Url: http://myurl.com Stack:    at
>   canopy.core.op_EqualsEquals[a](a item, String value) in
>   C:\projects\canopy \src\canopy\canopy.fs:line 437    at
>   Program.clo@24.Invoke(Unit _arg1) in
>   C:\Users\jj06848\Projects\AUPE2ETest\
>   AUPE2ETest\CanopyTest\Program.fs:line 28    at
>   canopy.runner.runtest$cont@93(suite suite, Test test, Unit unitVar) in
>   C:\ projects\canopy\src\canopy\runner.fs:line 102*

according to the docs both of these should be successful. I have several other places in my test where I attempt to pass an IWebElement into a assertion but all seem to have the same error. For example:

```
let bidHistoryResults = (elements ".table-striped")
let bidHistoryRows = bidHistoryResults.[2] |> elementsWithin "tr"
let firstRow = bidHistoryRows.[1] |> elementsWithin "td"
let secondRow = bidHistoryRows.[2] |> elementsWithin "td"
firstRow.[6] == "$15.93"
```

I am new to both F# and Canopy, hopefully someone can give me a push in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: According to Chris the documentation indicates that this will work, but the code does not allow it. A fix should be coming in a future update.